# Where are Firefox Flash temporary files?

Tags: firefox, flash, tmp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I access Flash files from streaming websites?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37267/how-can-i-access-flash-files-from-streaming-websites)

When playing Flash multimedia on Firefox eg. a Youtube video, the files used to be stored in `/tmp/` , but they do not appear there any more. Where are these temporary files stored?

Comment: Great question!