# How do I download a YouTube video?

Tags: software-recommendation

What are instructions on how to download videos from YouTube?

---

## Notice: Terms of Service Violation

Please be aware that by following any of the answers below, you will be violating YouTube's [Terms of Service (TOS)](https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms). In particular, from Section 5.B.:

> Content is provided to you AS IS. You may access Content for your information and personal use solely as intended through the provided functionality of the Service and as permitted under these Terms of Service. You shall not download any Content unless you see a “download” or similar link displayed by YouTube on the Service for that Content. You shall not copy, reproduce, distribute, transmit, broadcast, display, sell, license, or otherwise exploit any Content for any other purposes without the prior written consent of YouTube or the respective licensors of the Content. YouTube and its licensors reserve all rights not expressly granted in and to the Service and the Content.

---

Comment: Well, just by watching video on YouTube You also violate TOS because You are **transmiting** Content...

Comment: And by watching you're **display**ing it as well.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

[youtube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl) is a great tool for downloading YouTube videos. [Install](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#installation) with:

```
sudo curl -L https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

Or with `pip` ([python3-pip](https://packages.ubuntu.com/python3-pip)):

```
sudo -H pip install --upgrade youtube-dl
```

Or from Ubuntu's repo (older version)

```
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
```

then use it this way:

```
youtube-dl [VIDEO_LINK]
```

For learning more about advance options, run

```
man youtube-dl
```

Or check out the [documentation](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#readme).

#### Original answer

For Firefox users:

You can install the [Video DownloadHelper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/) addon in Firefox and download any embedded object, including YouTube videos.

[image]

[image]

Comment: not available for firefox 35

Comment: Youtube is not in the list of supported sites, I removed video-downloadhelper.

Comment: @PaulRougieux it is works with my latest Firefox per this day (current version 47.0). I've tested it downloading several Youtube videos, on my Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: `youtube-dl` by `apt-get` installs older version which doesn't work. [Manual Installation](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#how-do-i-update-youtube-dl) using `wget` as explained here worked.

Answer (score 337):

### [youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/)

Installation from official site:

```
sudo curl -L https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

It's also on Ubuntu repos but you will often need to keep it up-to-date with `sudo youtube-dl -U`

Installation and ugrade from `pip` ([/](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3-pip)):

```
sudo -H pip install --upgrade youtube-dl
```

Usage:

```
youtube-dl YouTube-(or-other-website)-video-link
```

So it will download the video.

You can also take a look at [this](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#readme) for very in-depth documentation on how to use it.

Comment: If you don't have `aptitude`, you can use `apt-get` instead. Please note also that before using `sudo aptitude install ...` or `sudo apt-get install ...` commands, you should first run `sudo aptitude update` or `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: sudo: aptitude: command not found

Comment: @siraj use `apt-get` instead.

Comment: It should be worth noting that new versions of youtube-dl can be downloaded from http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/

Comment: I recommend to run `sudo youtube-dl -U` right after apt-get.

Comment: @modosansreves Kinda funny that it suggests restarting `youtube-dl` just before closing itself :p

Comment: keep in mind, that youtube-dl is able to download from many other sites too

Comment: Run these before you start the download `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8 -y ...
sudo apt-get update ...
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`...

Comment: Does this app have a quality option? To select from the many prerendered formats youtube has readily available

Comment: @ThorSummoner You can use --max-quality or --format options.           Example :                                                  youtube-dl http://www.youtube.com/videolink --max-quality 360p  or                                                           youtube-dl http://www.youtube.com/videolink --format mp4

Comment: It gives me an error:   File "/usr/bin/youtube-dl", line 1406, in <genexpr>
    url_map = dict((ud['itag'][0], ud['url'][0] + '&signature=' + ud['sig'][0]) for ud in url_data) KeyError: 'sig' I'm on Elementary OS Luna.

Comment: Instead of messing around with PPAs, just use `sudo pip install youtube-dl`. @modosansreves I strongly disagree, programs should not mess with things installed by a package manager. Next time there's an upgrade in the official repo, dpkg might freak out because of the modified files.

Comment: what is the destination of downloaded file?

Comment: @m2j By default youtube-dl will download the files in the working directory of the Terminal that you have opened.

Comment: `apt-get` installation on Debian stable could not download videos from youtube. But `pip` installed a more recent version of youtube-dl which worked fine.  See also  @Prateek Joshi 's answer below, in addition to @nyuszika7h 's comment.

Comment: Disclaimer: I am only suggesting what is possible. Legal or not, you decide. The official word from Section 5 of the Terms and Conditions   


https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms  


You shall not download any Content unless you see a “download” or similar link displayed by YouTube on the Service for that Content.   

That said, in addition to downloading videos using youtube-dl, you can use the -x option like the example below to download and extract only the audio portion of the video:  


youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IDofTheVideo

Comment: Its installed but not downloading ...

Answer (score 54):

**[Minitube](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/minitube/)**

[image: Install minitube]

> Minitube is a YouTube desktop application.
>   With it you can watch YouTube videos in a new way: you type a keyword, Minitube gives you an endless video stream.
>   Minitube is not about cloning the original YouTube web interface, it aims to create a new TV-like experience.

It does not require *Flash Player*. From this application you can watch and download videos.

---

[image: Screenshoot1]

[image: Screenshoot2]

Comment: I'm wondering why no one mention this as well. By the way, a Ubuntu or Linux screen shot would be nice.

Comment: This is not really what the question was referring to. Can you download youtube videos from here?

Comment: This doesn't work on my Ubuntu 13.04, always crashes after 10 seconds.

Comment: It seems the download function is not working anymore

Comment: @Marronsuisse as one of the reviewers in the ubuntu app store said you need to install `phonon-backend-vlc` to avoid the crash when installing on 13.04.

Comment: As at May 2014, I checked this out and minitube seems to be a dead project. The newer (PAID) version is is minitube-ubuntu and you cannot get it for free. Apparently many reveiws on software centre show that the old minitube crashes.

Answer (score 31):

Browser addon: 
http://www.clipconverter.cc/addon/

[image]

Other sites that can be used:

http://www.clipconverter.cc/ 
http://keepvid.com/ 
http://www.listentoyoutube.com/

And this software is also great:

http://www.4kdownload.com/

[image]

Comment: This excellent chromium extension seems to have been deleted. Do you know a way to have this functionality yet? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, youtube doesn't allow to have this kind of extensions. but i have found a way around it. I will update my answer in a minute

Comment: Thank you @Jeggy, your suggestion is splendid. I have successfully installed this extension and it's working pretty fine on my Ubuntu system. Nevertheless I find a major issue when trying to install the same extension using your procedure in a Windows Based system, the extension installs but won't work. I would appreciate a lot if you provide some of your experience on this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should work just as good on Windows :/ I do not have any Windows machine close to me at the moment sorry :( but i will try it with Windows soon and maybe i'll update this if i'll get it to work

Comment: This doesn't work anymore.

Comment: yeah sorry, I don't know if you're interested but I've updated my answer with alternatives like 3rd party sites and a great software link

Comment: Great, 4kdownload is good. May the force be with you!!

Comment: I find https://askubuntu.com/a/390423/592207 the simplest answer, since you probably have VLC installed and it only takes two short keys and a copy-pasting.
Worked for me when 3rd party solutions didn't (Video with link access)

Answer (score 29):

I think that the simplest way to download a video from YouTube, without installing any plugin or software, is with [savefrom.net](http://en.savefrom.net/). And here is the video demonstrating [How to download YouTube videos using the ss trick](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gt2SmMprL48). Let's say you want to download the below video:

[image: Video to download]

On your address bar, add `ss` in front of `youtube.com` and hit <kbd>Enter ↵</kbd>.

[image: How to]

Now you will be redirected to [savefrom.net](https://savefrom.net). On your right, click on the video quality you want to download.

[image: Download]

Comment: that site allows downloads under 200 MB only

Comment: Savefrom made my day :-) all the other alternatives were somehow blocked, thank you for sharing.

Comment: @asoundmove You are welcome.

Comment: Actually now I downloaded 700+ MB video in H.264 under 2 minutes.

Answer (score 16):

### [cclive](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cclive)

[Install cclive](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/cclive)

We are able to download free content from YouTube or other streaming sites with this easy-to-use command-line tool.

> **cclive** is primarily a "video download tool" but it can also be used along side with video player software, like "mplayer", for viewing streamed videos instead of the Adobe flash player.

To download a video from a given location (on YouTube press the *"Share"* button to get the URL to a video). Copy this link and issue clive from a terminal with e.g. the following command:

```
cclive -s best http://youtu.be/D6z6hn6wZlg
```

There are plenty of other options to control download behaviour including options to choose the download format that are all nicely documented in the manpage. We can also queue a list of URLs from a file.

(Changed -f to -s; -f is deprecated).

Available for Ubuntu 18.10 and older only.

Answer (score 16):

First, if you don't have **wget**, install it:

```
sudo apt-get install wget
```

Use this Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T

use strict;
use warnings;

#
##  Calomel.org  ,:,  Download YouTube videos and music using wget
##    Script Name : youtube_wget_video.pl
##    Version     : 0.38
##    Valid from  : March 2014
##    URL Page    : https://calomel.org/youtube_wget.html
##    OS Support  : Linux, Mac OSX, OpenBSD, FreeBSD or any system with perl
#                `:`
## Two arguments
##    $1 YouTube URL from the browser
##    $2 Prefix to the file name of the video (optional)
#

############  options  ##########################################

# Option: what file type do you want to download? The string is used to search
# in the YouTube URL so you can choose mp4, webm, avi or flv. mp4 seems to
# work on the most players like Android, iPod, iPad, iPhones, VLC media player
# and MPlayer.
my $fileType = "mp4";

# Option: what visual resolution or quality do you want to download? List
# multiple values just in case the highest quality video is not available, the
# script will look for the next resolution. You can choose "highres" for 4k,
# "hd1080" for 1080p, "hd720" for 720p, "itag=18" which means standard
# definition 640x380 and "itag=17" which is mobile resolution 144p (176x144).
# The script will always prefer to download the highest resolution video format
# from the list if available.
my $resolution = "hd720,itag=18";

# Option: How many times should the script retry the download if wget fails for
# any reason? Do not make this too high as a reoccurring error will just hit
# YouTube over and over again.
my $retryTimes = 5;

# Option: do you want the resolution of the video in the file name? zero(0) is
# no and one(1) is yes. This option simply puts "_hd1080.mp4" or similar at the
# end of the file name.
my $resolutionFilename = 0;

# Option: turn on DEBUG mode. Use this to reverse engineering this code if you are
# making changes or you are building your own YouTube download script.
my $DEBUG=0;

#################################################################

## Initialize retry loop and resolution variables
$ENV{PATH} = "/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin";
my $prefix = "";
my $retry = 1;
my $retryCounter = 0;
my $resFile = "unknown";
my $user_url = "";
my $user_prefix = "";

## Collect the URL from the command line argument
chomp($user_url = $ARGV[0]);
my $url = "$1" if ($user_url =~ m/^([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\&\?\=\:\.\/]+)$/ or die "\nError: Illegal characters in YouTube URL\n\n" );

## Declare the user defined file name prefix if specified
if (defined($ARGV[1])) {
    chomp($user_prefix = $ARGV[1]);
    $prefix = "$1" if ($user_prefix =~ m/^([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\.\ ]+)$/ or die "\nError: Illegal characters in filename prefix\n\n" );
}

## Retry getting the video if the script fails for any reason
while ( $retry != 0 && $retryCounter < $retryTimes ) {

    ## Download the html code from the YouTube page suppling the page title and the
    ## video URL. The page title will be used for the local video file name and the
    ## URL will be sanitized and passed to wget for the download.
    my $html = `wget -4Ncq -e convert-links=off --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies /dev/null --no-check-certificate "$url" -O-`  or die  "\nThere was a problem downloading the HTML file.\n\n";

    ## Format the title of the page to use as the file name
    my ($title) = $html =~ m/<title>(.+)<\/title>/si;
    $title =~ s/[^\w\d]+/_/g or die "\nError: we could not find the title of the HTML page. Check the URL.\n\n";
    $title =~ s/_youtube//ig;
    $title =~ s/^_//ig;
    $title = lc ($title);
    $title =~ s/_amp//ig;

    ## Collect the URL of the video from the HTML page
    my ($download) = $html =~ /"url_encoded_fmt_stream_map"(.*)/ig;

    # Print all of the separated strings in the HTML page
    print "\n$download\n\n" if ($DEBUG == 1);

    # This is where we look through the HTMl code and select the file type and
    # video quality.
    my @urls = split(',', $download);
    OUTERLOOP:
    foreach my $val (@urls) {
    #   print "\n$val\n\n";

        if ($val =~ /$fileType/) {
            my @res = split(',', $resolution);
            foreach my $ress (@res) {
                if ($val =~ /$ress/) {
                    print "\n\nGOOD\n\n" if ($DEBUG == 1);
                    print "$val\n" if ($DEBUG == 1);
                    $resFile = $ress;
                    $resFile = "sd640" if ( $ress =~ /itag=18/ );
                    $resFile = "mobil176" if ( $ress =~ /itag=17/ );
                    $download = $val;
                    last OUTERLOOP;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ## Clean up the URL by translating unicode and removing unwanted strings
    $download =~ s/\:\ \"//;
    $download =~ s/%3A/:/g;
    $download =~ s/%2F/\//g;
    $download =~ s/%3F/\?/g;
    $download =~ s/%3D/\=/g;
    $download =~ s/%252C/%2C/g;
    $download =~ s/%26/\&/g;
    $download =~ s/sig=/signature=/g;
    $download =~ s/\\u0026/\&/g;
    $download =~ s/(type=[^&]+)//g;
    $download =~ s/(fallback_host=[^&]+)//g;
    $download =~ s/(quality=[^&]+)//g;

    ## Clean up the URL
    my ($youtubeurl) = $download =~ /(http?:.+)/;

    ## URL title additon
    my ($titleurl) = $html =~ m/<title>(.+)<\/title>/si;
    $titleurl =~ s/ - YouTube//ig;
    $titleurl =~ s/ /%20/ig;

    ## Combine the YouTube URL and title string
    $download = "$youtubeurl\&title=$titleurl";

    ## A bit more cleanup as YouTube
    $download =~ s/&+/&/g;
    $download =~ s/&itag=\d+&signature=/&signature=/g;

    ## Combine file variables into the full file name
    my $filename = "unknown";
    if ($resolutionFilename == 1) {
        $filename = "$prefix$title\_$resFile.$fileType";
    }
    else {
        $filename = "$prefix$title.$fileType";
    }

    ## Process check: Are we currently downloading this exact same video? Two of the
    ## same wget processes will overwrite themselves and corrupt the video.
    my $running = `ps auwww | grep [w]get | grep -c "$filename"`;
    print "\nNumber of the same wgets running: $running\n" if ($DEBUG == 1);
    if ($running >= 1)
    {
        print "\nAlready $running process, exiting." if ($DEBUG == 1);
        exit 0;
    };

    ## Print the long, sanitized YouTube URL for testing and debugging
    print "\n$download\n" if ($DEBUG == 1);

    ## Print the file name of the video collected from the web page title for us to see on the cli
    print "\n Download: $filename\n\n";

    ## Background the script. Use "ps" if you need to look for the process
    ## running or use "ls -al" to look at the file size and date.
    fork and exit;

    ## Download the video
    system("wget", "-4Ncq", "-e", "convert-links=off", "--load-cookies", "/dev/null", "--tries=10", "--timeout=20", "--no-check-certificate", "$download", "-O", "$filename");

    ## Print the error code of wget
    print "     error code: $?\n" if ($DEBUG == 1);

    ## Exit Status: Check if the file exists and we received the correct error code
    ## from system call. If the download experienced any problems the script will run again and try
    ## continue the download till the file is downloaded.

    if ($? == 0 && -e "$filename" && ! -z "$filename")
    {
        print " Finished: $filename\n\n" if ($DEBUG == 1);
        $retry = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        print STDERR "\n FAILED: $filename\n\n" if ($DEBUG == 1);
        $retry = 1;
        $retryCounter++;
        sleep $retryCounter;
    }

} # while

#### EOF #####
```

Copy this script to a .txt file and rename it `youtube_wget.pl`.

Make it executable, using the following command:

```
chmod 755 youtube_wget.pl
```

When you want to download in the terminal, type:

```
./youtube_wget.pl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ejkm5uGoxs4
```

Change the YouTube URL to your YouTube video URL.

Save Location: The video will be saved in your current directory.

Source: [YouTube Downloader Wget Perl Script](https://calomel.org/youtube_wget.html)

Comment: I am sure that the OP has aready installed `wget` since he asked how to used in a particular way.

Comment: Given that this is a script that only invokes `wget` (and exposes a completely different interface to the user), I would go with [the `youtube-dl` answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/432370/82993) instead. `youtube-dl` is much more powerful.

Comment: you can check whether the download is finished by :`ps -aux | grep wget`

Comment: worked great on my machine (14.04)

Comment: can't get to work

Answer (score 15):

### For Firefox users:

As [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166488/downloading-youtube-videos-with-minitube) to that question is probably more valid here, I'll present it here for convenience.

You can use `flashgot`, which is an addon for Firefox that I have found extremely useful for downloading videos from YouTube and *other* sites. (You still require the flash-plugin in your browser, however, for the video to be detected by `flashgot`.)

- Install `flashgot` from the [official Mozilla addons site](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashgot/?src=search) and restart Firefox. Make sure that the addon is enabled; check by going to menu *Tools* → *Addons* → *Extensions*. From the `flashgot` entry in the extensions tab you can also set a number of preferences.
- Navigate to your YouTube video and set the **quality** in the YouTube video settings and start the video playing for a few seconds and then pause it.
- Right click in the YouTube page and select `flashgot media`; there probably will be more than one video; either simply download them both or choose the larger file size (which will be the higher quality video). You can either use your browser's download manager or another program set via the `flashgot options`.

[image]

Comment: especially powerful with axel as download manager to download at greatest speed (http://askubuntu.com/a/180370/47206)

Comment: I use it with the DownThemAll download manager. It can even sniff some streams that are harder to find.

Comment: Both Flashgot and DownThemAll  were broken by Firefox Quantum (57). They still work (for now) in Firefox SE (52).

Answer (score 10):

I want to suggest a method for downloading YouTube videos using VLC media player in simple four steps:

1. Open the link of the video as network streaming in VLC media player. (`Ctrl + N` or Media > Open Network Stream...)
2. Select media info and copy the location (`Ctrl + I` or Right click on the video area > Tools > Media information )
3. Paste it in your browser's address bar
4. Save it.

Comment: Instead of saving using browser, I use uGet and now able to resume the download.. Thanks alot :)

Comment: I like this solution

Comment: I don't understand why this hasn't got many upvotes! This is the most straight forward method I found amongst all. No need to download any external piece of software, and almost everyone uses VLC. Kudos to you.. :)

Comment: is there an option to select media quality?

Comment: This worked on Ubuntu 18.04. The "superpctricks" link goes to a deadend now, but the 4 steps worked fine. Thank you hmayag!

Comment: Still works on ubuntu 18 :)

Answer (score 9):

4kdownloader! Other than downloading videos from URLs, it can also download entire playlists, and also convert them to MP3 or other formats if required.

http://www.4kdownload.com/

I am using it for long time, it's simple and easy to use, and it has a GUI interface for Ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: First time hear about this. It's awesome!

Comment: thanks a lot, i didnt know about this option...this is the best

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE**

The bytubed is no longer maintained. So the new solution is going with the famous, but command-line [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/). It's regularly maintained and runs fine.

1. To update it

   ```
   youtube-dl -U
   ```
2. And to download a video or playlist

   ```
   youtube-dl -c -t URL_HERE
   ```
3. And if there is a file with URLs then

   ```
   youtube-dl -c -t -a urls.txt
   ```

#### Old answer

I know it is answered, but I'm shocked that none explicitly mentioned [Bytubed](http://msram.github.com/bytubed/). It's simply the best to me when it comes to YouTube download.
Just do install it and then go to Firefox's menu *Tools* → *Bytubed*.

The only downside is it works with Firefox only, but to me it's not a downside since I use Firefox for all my browsing...

Comment: No longer applicable. That link states: "BYTubeD disabled! (Sep 27, 2013)"

Comment: see updated answer

Answer (score 5):

You could also try using Clipgrab. It can download videos from YouTube via the clipboard, or you can search via the application for videos. The PPA is [here](https://launchpad.net/~clipgrab-team/+archive/ppa).

You can use these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:clipgrab-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install clipgrab
```

Comment: I used to use 4kyoutube, but ClipGrap is definitely immensely faster and, best of all, allows unlimited downloads (4kyoutube is proprietary).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Python command line program **[youtube-dl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Youtube-dl)**.

1. To install the program youtube-dl, type the following commands in your terminal:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install python-pip
   $ sudo pip install --upgrade youtube_dl
   ```
2. To download YouTube videos from the terminal, use:

   ```
   $youtube-dl <video_url>
   ```
3. To see **different quality and formats available** use `option -F`. Then use the **format code** which will be shown after using option -F, to download it in the desired format.

   $ youtube-dl -F 
      $ youtube-dl -f
4. To download the whole **playlist** use

   ```
   $ youtube-dl -citw <playlist_url>
   ```
5. To download the **entire channel** use

   ```
   $ youtube-dl -citw ytuser:<channel_name>
   ```

Comment: Bless you! This helped me on Debian. On Debian Linux, the update functionality of youtube-dl is not enabled. Therefore this was the only clean solution to install the most recent version: ```sudo pip install --upgrade youtube_dl```

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for plugins. This is a simple and excellent solution:

[monsieurvideo/get-flash-videos](https://github.com/monsieurvideo/get-flash-videos) on GitHub

[The original site](https://web.archive.org/web/20151213112022/http://code.google.com/p/get-flash-videos/) is now found as [read-only archive](https://code.google.com/archive/p/get-flash-videos/).

Answer (score 4):

**To install `youtube-dl`**:

- Recommended way (latest version):

  1. Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or searching **Terminal** in the dash.
  2. Install `youtube-dl` with this command (you'll be prompted for your password):

     ```
     sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl && sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
     ```
- Not recommended way (older version):

  1. Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or searching **Terminal** in the dash.
  2. Install `youtube-dl` with this command (you'll be prompted for your password):

     ```
     sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
     ```

---

**To use `youtube-dl`:**

1. To select where to save the video, you can follow these steps:

   - Type `cd` on the terminal.
   - Press <kbd>Space</kbd>
   - Drag the folder from File Manager and drop it on the terminal.
   - If you skip this step, the video will be saved on your home folder.
2. To download the video you can use one of these procedures:

   2.1. Run `youtube-dl video_url` where `video_url` is the URL of the video.

   2.2. If do you want to download many videos, you can follow these steps instead of 2.1:

   - Run the below command:

     ```
     xargs youtube-dl
     ```
   - Repeat the following procedure for each link:

     - Paste a link.
     - Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
   - Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

   2.3. If do you have a plain text file with a list of links, you can download them this way:

   - Type `cat` on the terminal.
   - Press <kbd>Space</kbd>
   - Drag the file form the File Manager and drop it on the terminal.
   - Press <kbd>Space</kbd>
   - Type `| xargs youtube-dl`
   - Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Now the video/s will download to the selected folder.

---

**Some final thoughts:**

- On the method 2.3 the final command should look like this:

  ```
  cat '/home/foo/Desktop/myawesomevideos.txt' | xargs youtube-dl
  ```
- You can also use the URL of a channel and `youtube-dl` will save the entire channel.
- You can update `youtube-dl` with `sudo youtube-dl -U`
- You can see all the options of `youtube-dl` with `youtube-dl --help`

---

**Thanks to [user185719](https://askubuntu.com/users/185719) and [Michael Grünewald](https://askubuntu.com/users/393291) by it's cotributions to this answer.**

Answer (score 3):

You can try [ytd-gtk](http://code.google.com/p/ytd-gtk/). It's a graphical frontend for [youtube-dl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Youtube-dl) and can download from a variety of video sites.

Answer (score 2):

There is [this Greasemonkey script on userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/25105). But I cannot vouch for it. Nor I can assert the security of such a script.

But it seems to work.

You will need to install [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/).

Answer (score 2):

There are so many ways of downloading YouTube videos.

### Application:

Personally I have used `MiniTube` as my application of choice for getting videos from YouTube. It's a real simple approach. Find the video by keyword, then download it.

### Command Line:

If you feel comfortable with the command line interface (or CLI as it is known) through your terminal application, try the `youtube-dl` command line approach.

### Websites:

Websites like [MediaConvertor](http://www.mediaconverter.org) or [Vixy Freecoder](http://vixy.net) can do this **without the need of installing extensions** for Firefox or Chrome/Chromium or native applications.

These 2 websites allows you to download in **different formats**. Both audio and Video formats. You plug in the link to the video on their site and wait for the conversion to complete and then you get the link for the download.

The bonus to the sites is that they are cross-platform much like the extensions approach. But if you want to free your browser from the clutter of extra things, then try the sites or the other suggestions others have mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Solved with a small shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# grabflash
#
# Finds any cached Flash videos in the kernel file handles list
# and copies them to the user Videos folder ; this gets around
# the new Flash players habit of opening a cache file in /tmp
# and immediately deleting it.
#
# Usage: Play the video until it's all cached. Run script.
#        The video will be copied to ~/Videos folder as FLV.
#

for I in $(pgrep -f libflashplayer.so)
    do ls -l /proc/$I/fd/* | \
    grep '/tmp/Flash' | \
    grep -o "/proc/$I/fd/\\S*" | \
    xargs --no-run-if-empty cp -t ~/Videos/
done
```

Comment: This method no longer works AFAIK, the new YouTube player doesn't seem to use the same caching method.

Answer (score 2):

I just did this for my **Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr)**.

You should try **clipgrab**. Other than the fact that you **can't**
download videos with more than **1080p quality** is a nice quick GUI for
YouTube download.

This is the 64 [version](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/mirrors/pub/getdeb/ubuntu/pool/apps/c/clipgrab/clipgrab_3.4.2-1~getdeb1_amd64.deb) and the 32 [version](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/mirrors/pub/getdeb/ubuntu/pool/apps/c/clipgrab/clipgrab_3.4.2-1~getdeb1_i386.deb). Just download and install from Ubuntu Software Center.

Then you straight up download videos. If you want the other
available formats (*.mp3 and more 'someone said it's useful') you are going to need [FFmpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg) and libavcodec-extra-53.

So run

```
$ sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-53

$ sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

It really comes in-handy.

Answer (score 2):

Those answers are **too** complex, so I'm going to help you without installing anything.

First go to your browser and enter [**this**](http://www.clipconverter.cc/) in the URL tab.

Next, enter the YouTube URL in the first box. For example, I'm going to use a Ubuntu YouTube link.
[image: The YouTube link image]

Then press **Continue**.

Now, once you pressed **Continue**, this will pop up.
[image: The YouTube image]

At the **Detected Media** tab, you can choose the quality of your video.

**720p** is **HD**.
**480p** is **HQ**.
**360p** is **SQ**.
**3GP** is **MV**.

Each type of quality takes up memory and downloading time depending on your internet. Just mess around and see what you like.

Now, at the **File Name** tab, you can change the name of the video when you download it. This is completely optional as you can change the name of it using the **rename** tab when you right click on it.

Next, you can change the **type** of video you want. For example, you want it to go on your iPod, you can easily change it to MP3.

I would highly recommend using **MP4** as its most commonly used.

[image: The file extender]

Finally, you can now press the **Start!** button to start the download!
[image: Start button]

Enjoy! =)

Comment: Please make sure to read through the [terms of use and privacy policy](http://www.clipconverter.cc/terms/) before using this service.

Answer (score 2):

As of now there is the GUI for a popular `Youtube-dl` available. Where you can manually configure all the settings and just paste & download from link. To install it:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install youtube-dlg
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy the URL of the YouTube video that you're watching
2. Open a new tab and hit `www.keepvid.com`
3. You'll find a text box at the top of the page. Paste the URL that you have copied into the box and click on <kbd>Download</kbd>
4. Run the Java applet when prompted (you have to have Java installed on the system or else this won't work)
5. Once done, you'll have various formats and qualities of the video, Right click on the one you find most suited and click `Save Link As` and save it.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome does not support YouTube downloading extensions by default.

But fortunately we can [install Google Chrome Extensions manually](http://www.howtogeek.com/120743/how-to-install-extensions-from-outside-the-chrome-web-store/) and that is how you are going to install third-party extensions like [SaveForm](https://sf-addon.com/helper/chrome/helper_last.crx) to Chrome and you would be able to download any video on YouTube (and many other sites) by clicking on Download button, just below the video.

This extension works on Opera Next, Firefox and Safari browsers as well. And they all works like charm on latest Ubuntu operating system.

Source: [Video TutsDB](http://video.tutsdb.com/2013/09/download-videos-from-youtube.html)

Answer (score 1):

A few more options:

**MediaHuman software**

- [YouTube to mp3](http://www.mediahuman.com/youtube-to-mp3-converter/) is proprietary but free (as in beer). Works beautifully on Ubuntu and is very easy to use. [Available in the Ubuntu Software Center](http://www.mediahuman.com/download/YouTubeToMP3.apt).
  [image]
- [YouTube Downloader](http://www.mediahuman.com/youtube-downloader/) is also proprietary but not free. You can grab a free trial version from the homepage. Not available in the USC.

  [image]
- There's also [YouTube to MP3 converter](http://www.mediahuman.com/youtube-to-mp3-converter/) which has the same featureset as YouTube to mp3 but supports a few more websites. This one is also free.

**YouTube Center**

[YouTube Center](https://github.com/YePpHa/YouTubeCenter/wiki) is an open-source extension for Chrome, Firefox, Opera and other browsers that enhances YouTube with a lot of added features. Among those features is the ability to directly download YouTube videos in a variety of different formats:

[image]

I always recommend installing the [developer version](https://github.com/YePpHa/YouTubeCenter/wiki/Developer-Version) of the extension as it comes with the latest bug fixes and new features.

Answer (score 1):

#### Download youtube-dl

```
wget https://yt-dl.org/downloads/2014.08.10/youtube-dl
chmod a+x youtube-dl
```

#### Download videos:

```
./youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRPVy_t1_IE
```

#### Download specific formats

See the formats:

```
./youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRPVy_t1_IE -F
```

Download it with `-f <val>`:

```
./youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRPVy_t1_IE -f 38
```

Answer (score 0):

Another tip: You can download YouTube videos without installing any package or program:

Open this site: [Site](http://keepvid.com/)

Add a YouTube URL:

[image]

Press *Download*:

[image]

Choose what type you want. You can also download it as only video with no sound, or just sound.

Once you press *Download Type*, it will start downloading.

Comment: it requires `java`

Answer (score 0):

There is an wonderful application from SM Team Called **SmTube**.

You can install SmTube by:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rvm/smplayer
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install smtube
```

Or download from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/smplayer/files/SMTube/14.8.0/smtube-14.8.0.tar.bz2/download?use_mirror=softlayer-sng)!!

[image]

Search any video (the video you want to download) and then right click on video and click on 'Record Video'.

[image]

From setting you can adjust the quality of video and destination of the video to save:

[image]

[image]