# How to download youtube videos like with realplayer in windows?

Tags: youtube, downloads, open-source

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Downloading a youtube video](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63270/downloading-a-youtube-video)

i use to download videos in window and was wondering if there is anything that is open source that can download the videos?
I am using Ubuntu 11.10
I am on a HP.

Answer (score 0):

The best program I have seen that can do this is [MiniTube](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/10/desktop-youtube-app-minitube-updates-adds-social-features/).  It allows you to search YouTube without using a web browser and also allows you to watch YouTube videos without having to use Flash.  MiniTube will also let you download the video you are watching and save it to the directory of your choice.

You can install minitube in Ubuntu by adding the official minitube PPA. Do this by opening a Terminal and entering the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/minitube
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install minitube
```

Another choice would be [UMPlayer](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/umplayer-ppa.html), which is simply a tricked-out frontend for mplayer. Among umplayer's many features is a YouTube search field and options to download videos. UMPlayer can be downloaded and installed by adding the Webupd8 Team UMPlayer PPA. Do this by opening a Terminal and entering the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/umplayer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install umplayer
```

If you have issues with subtitle files or UMPlayer is buggy or will not function, you may need to upgrade your mplayer from the Mplayer Daily PPA. Do this by opening a Terminal and entering the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:motumedia/mplayer-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Hopefully one of these programs does what you need it to do.

Comment: be sure to mark this as your accepted answer, and I hope one of these programs does the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a firefox addon called [video download helper](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/?src=search)

with that you can download from youtube and MANY others.
and also convert them to the extension mp3/wma/mp4 of your choice

Answer (score 0):

You can save any Flash video by doing the following:

1) Load the video in a browser, wait for it to finish buffering.

2) Determine the flash plugin process id (pid):

```
$ ps ax|grep npviewer
```

The pid is in the first column.

3) Find the video:

```
$ ls /proc/<pid>/fd -l |grep Flash
```

This lists all open flash videos, which were originally saved to a file in /tmp and then deleted. If you have multiple videos open, they will all be listed here. Use mplayer to find the correct one.

4) Copy the video:

```
$ cp /proc/<pid>/<vid_num> your_video.fla
```

5) Make sure it worked:

```
$ mplayer your_video.fla
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple and easy answer: [www.keepvid.com](http://www.keepvid.com)**

All you need to do to download videos from YouTube is to copy and paste the YouTube video's link into the bar where it allows you to paste a link. Then press Download, and it'll give you a set of download links that allow you to download the video in various formats and qualities.

To run this, the only thing you need is Java.