# Downloading youtube videos with minitube

Tags: video, downloads, youtube, minitube

Minitube has been working great for a lot of the youtube links, but for videos that require confirmation that you're older than 18, they don't work. Is there something I can do about this?

Or if there's a better way to download the videos do tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a terminal you may wish to give a chance to youtube-dl which can be easily installed by dropping `sudo apt-get install youtube-dl` and its usage is quite easy: simply copy the youtube url and add it in the terminal just after `youtube-dl` as shown in the next example:

```
youtube-dl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yQEaXAoB6Ck
```

*This code will download Baltimora Chinese Restaurant video.*

This will resut in the flv video to be downloaded in the folder where the terminal resides at the very moment that you start downloading, so make sure you first change directory to your videos folder.

Another excellent option is via GUI, by using [Mobile Media Converter by MikSoft](http://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverterDown.htm)

[image]

And or [JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/). JDownloader will also allow you to choose which video format you want to donload based on the available formats in youtube, which may include but not limited to: mp4, flv, ogv, mp3 and a few other.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm downloading youtube video through `Firefox` with `Easy Youtube Video Downloader 6.2` addon.
Try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flashgot`, which is an addon for `firefox` that I have found extremely useful for downloading videos from Youtube and other sites. (You still require the flash-plugin in your browser, however, for the video to be detected by `flashgot`.)

- Install `flashgot` from [the official Mozilla addons site](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashgot/?src=search).
- Navigate to your Youtube video and set the quality in the youtube video settings and start the video playing for a few seconds and then pause it.
- Right click in the Youtube page and select `flashgot media`; there probably will be more than one video; either simply download them both or choose the larger file size (which will be the higher quality video). You can either use your browser's download manager or another program set via the `flashgot options`.