# Videos Downloading problem with MultiGet

Tags: downloads

I have installed MultiGet to my machine and I don't know how to use it. I tried to download videos from YouTube by pasting URL to MultiGet but it didn't work. So what should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

**MultiGet** likely does not support downloading YouTube streams (tested with version 1.2.0). If you specifically want to download videos from YouTube, there are several other ways such as `youtube-dl`, `ytd-gtk` and many web browser extensions.

See this question for other YouTube downloading solutions: [How do I download a YouTube video?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63270/how-do-i-download-a-youtube-video)

Comment: Can not provide a definitive one, edited answer. The last version seems to be from Nov 2010 (Ubuntu repo has even older one). Even if it had at some point supported, concerning how often YouTube API changes (making most of the downloaders obsolete until they are updated), I think it would be very unlikely that it still worked.