# How to download YouTube videos via HTTPS

Tags: youtube, https

I am unable to access YouTube on HTTP. But I can access the same on an HTTPS.

When I executed the command `wget https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StJLvbPIvTw` it returned the following response:

```
--2013-03-04 13:09:28--  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StJLvbPIvTw
Resolving www.youtube.com (www.youtube.com)... 74.125.236.167, 74.125.236.160, 74.125.236.164, ...
Connecting to www.youtube.com (www.youtube.com)|74.125.236.167|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Please guide me on how to download the YouTube videos on HTTPS.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/63270/how-do-i-download-a-youtube-video, but because of the *https* part it might not be one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found from some other Question:-
Use the URL [savefrom.net](http://savefrom.net) and type in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StJLvbPIvTw. Press Download button and you can download it in any format :))
No matter whether you access it via HTTPS or HTTP

you can download the chrome app also from here>> http://en.savefrom.net/user.php

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Just don't use wget.

```
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StJLvbPIvTw
```

Works on my system.

Comment: does it works with HTTPS too??

Comment: i tried it, but it gave the error:- `[youtube] Setting language

[youtube] StJLvbPIvTw: Downloading video webpage

[youtube] StJLvbPIvTw: Downloading video info webpage
ERROR: "token" parameter not in video info for unknown reason`

Comment: did you copy-paste my commands? it works perfectly here. Try it for some other youtubes. Here is the source code: https://bitbucket.org/rg3/youtube-dl/src/4ad292a3161c0e3bc6d7ff3459e4fb2d2e790b70/youtube-dl

Comment: @vipin8169 You probably need a more recent version of `youtube-dl`.

Comment: yes i copy pasted your command.

Comment: @qbi how to get the latest version then, i used `sudo apt-get install youtube-dl`. i hope it gets the latest version by default

Comment: What Ubuntu version do you use?

Comment: i use version 12.04

Comment: @vipin8169 No, the command won't get the latest version as the version the Ubuntu repositories is quite old (quite old considering how often Youtube API changes, affecting all these downloader programs). I edited the instructions on how to get the latest version (as of writing this comment, edit not yet approved). I don't know if there are any https related fixes in the newer version(s), but you should try anyway.

Answer (score 1):

you can't use wget to download video from youtube because the adress is just the webpage of the video, not the video file.

youtube-dl works with https (actual version).

i don't know if you have fixed your problem with youtube-dl, but if you followed the installation procedure mentioned on the website (and installed it in /usr/local/bin), you should specify the output folder, like this :

```
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo youtube-dl -o '/home/username/Music/test.flv' https://www.uTube.com/v?=
```

by default youtube-dl download the best quality

another alternative is [clipgrab](http://clipgrab.de/en).

it comes with a nice GUI :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the **Video Download helper** addon on firefox. Works great for me

Here's the link :

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/?src=ss

and it works with HTTPS.

Comment: I recommend editing this to provide a link also, and if possible, information about how to install/use it. Also, have you verified this works over HTTPS?

Comment: i am unable to open https in firefox, only chrome could open it. don't know what's the issue

Comment: are you using a proxy server or vpn? make sure firefox is correctly configured

Answer (score 0):

According to your question and your location it might be that you are behind some restrictive network settings. So best is to enable HTTPS by default. You can install the plugin [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) for Firefox or Google Chrome. This plugin tries to access YouTube as well as other pages per HTTPS by default. Furthermore the [Firefox addons page](http://addons.mozilla.org) has several plugins which allow you to download videos. For instance [Video DownloadHelper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/) works on several video pages. With both plugins combined 
you can download videos over HTTPS.

If you need a plugin for Chromium, have a look at this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/177808/236) and also other answers for this question.

Comment: I need a Chrome app, in firefox it's not working