# How can i download youtube videos one after another automatically from terminal

Tags: video, downloads, youtube

How can i download youtube videos one after another  automatically from terminal?  is there any chance to download youtube videos one after the another automatically from terminal??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was quite tempted to mark this question as a duplicate of [How do I download a YouTube video?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63270/how-do-i-download-a-youtube-video)

However, your question is remotely different because you want to download YouTube videos *one after another*, not a single YouTube video. This is also simple: use the program `youtube-dl` as suggested in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/145563/223688). `youtube-dl` can also take a *list* of URLs as parameters and download them one by one.

For instance,

```
youtube-dl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CP8CNp-vksc http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmOXHH3DTwg
```

Comment: or `youtube-dl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CP8CNp-vksc ; youtube-dl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmOXHH3DTwg`

Comment: yes, or `for link in http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M0Y9bbtlB5w http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBtPhaF5OhA; do youtube-dl $link; done` -- many roads lead to Rome. I went for the shortest one ;)

Comment: yes, your command was an easy one.