# using youtube-dl to download entire youtube channel

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

So I'm trying to download an entire youtube channel using youtube-dl. I know that if you use the -F command, it gives you a list of the quality type of the videos. My question is this: how to download the best quality of all the videos so the download doesnt default to 460p or something low like that.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

This answer won't work on older versions of youtube-dl. You need to update youtube-dl to the latest version. You can either install the latest version of youtube-dl locally inside a Python virtual environment (*virtualenv*), or you can download the latest version of youtube-dl and install it with `pip` (`sudo apt remove youtube-dl && sudo apt install python-pip && pip install --user youtube-dl`). youtube-dl is also a snap package. To install it type:

```
sudo snap install youtube-dl # launch it with snap run youtube-dl
```

Open the terminal and type:

```
youtube-dl -f best -ciw -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" -v <url-of-channel>
```

...where `<url-of-channel>` is replaced by the URL of the channel.

*Note:* If you are downloading a lot of videos, you should change directories to the directory where you want to save the videos before you start downloading them.

#### Explanation

```
-f, --format FORMAT
    video format code. The special name "best" will pick the best quality.

-c, --continue                   
    force resume of partially downloaded files

-i, --ignore-errors              
    continue on download errors, for example to skip unavailable videos in a channel 

-w, --no-overwrites
    do not overwrite files

-o, --output
    Output filename template, this example functions similarly to the old --title option

-v, --verbose
    print various debugging information
```

Comment: That was a good answer. Maybe if you just want to update it because I applied that command and I got this warning `WARNING: --title is deprecated. Use -o "%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s" ` (**but** your command worked successfully despite the warning)

Comment: @karel  since the channel that i wanna download contains ,many videos thus i can't download them in one sitting. What to do in such case?

Comment: @Vicrobot I don't know if this is exactly your question, correct me if I'm wrong, but sometimes I download an entire series of programming tutorials from YouTube and I need to start it from the terminal, lock the screen, and leave it until it finishes. My other favorite source of knowledge is [Leo Wattenberg](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/145802/leo-wattenberg) who is YouTube Contributor, Google Top Contributor, YouTube Certified in channel growth and content strategy. Leo Wattenberg is also the top all time answerer of questions tagged with `youtube` at Web Applications Q&A.

Comment: @karel I have a channel that contains about 250 videos. Now i want to download it. Is there any direct way to do these downloadings in partitions?

Comment: Are they all in one channel or all in one playlist, then you can download the entire [channel](https://superuser.com/questions/1138086/download-an-entire-youtube-channel-with-youtube-dl-and-automatically-resume-if-i/1138088#1138088) or [playlist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/857989/get-watch-link-for-all-videos-of-a-youtube-channel/857992#857992). Or else you can copy all the YouTube video links to a text file, each link on a separate line and download them all [like this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334081/downloading-multiple-files-with-youtube-dl/334097?s=2|76.3609#334097).

Comment: @karel sorry for such stupid questions. I just figured out that it is itself taking care of previous downloads. :P

Comment: I just want to note - as far as I can tell, all of the arguments are varying degrees of optional, and the default behavior if youtube-dl is given a channel is to download the whole channel. the most important addition here seems to me to be -ciw, which affect retry.

Comment: You should also add `--download-archive downloaded.txt` to resume downloading - this will skip existing files

Comment: @tjorriemorrie could you please elaborate on how to modify this command `youtube-dl -f best -ciw -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" -v <url-of-channel>` to use `--download-archive downloaded.txt` Thanks.

Comment: As of today, `-f best` option **WILL NOT** give you the best resolution. You would be better off in removing that flag. Check with and without before queuing your batch download.

Comment: @nehemiah I tested the `-f best` option of youtube-dl and it still works properly in my computer. By "works properly" I mean the `-f best` option downloads the best available resolution. Use a command of the form `youtube-dl -F URL` to list all of the available resolutions for the YouTube video at link URL.

Comment: @karel I guess the issue could be in the way audio and video are combined. When I exclude the `-f` flag I'm noticing the best video and best audio are downloaded separately and merged using `ffmpeg`. When I include `-f` flag it directly downloads the `.mp4` which is just 720p. I'm running youtube-dl version 2019.10.22 in MacOS Catalina. Apologies for not being an Ubuntu user in an Ubuntu forum. If it works, just great. Never mind 

Comment: Wanted to chime in and mirror what @nehem said. I'm on Windows 10 with the May 8th, 2020 build of youtube-dl and removing -f best did indeed bump the quality of the downloads significantly.

Comment: Thanks @JulianJocque for confirming that on Win10!!

Answer (score 18):

**TL;DR** use the `-f 'bestvideo[height>=720]+bestaudio/best'` flag to get a higher resolution. The full command I used is:

`youtube-dl -f "bestvideo[height>=720]+bestaudio/best" -ciw -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" -v <url-of-channel>`

Here is why `-f best` might not give you the highest resolution.

When you use the `-F` flag to list the possible file formats, sometimes it lists a 360p format as "best", for example:

```
youtube-dl -F https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FmZXCqqx6q0
[youtube] FmZXCqqx6q0: Downloading webpage
[info] Available formats for FmZXCqqx6q0:
format code  extension  resolution note
249    webm   audio only tiny   61k , opus @ 50k (48000Hz), 12.74MiB
250    webm   audio only tiny   80k , opus @ 70k (48000Hz), 16.87MiB
140    m4a    audio only tiny  132k , m4a_dash container, mp4a.40.2@128k (44100Hz), 31.35MiB
251    webm   audio only tiny  158k , opus @160k (48000Hz), 33.34MiB
...
244    webm   854x480    480p  271k , vp9, 30fps, video only, 35.05MiB
398    mp4    1280x720   720p  443k , av01.0.05M.08, 30fps, video only, 102.27MiB
247    webm   1280x720   720p  480k , vp9, 30fps, video only, 63.02MiB
136    mp4    1280x720   720p  489k , avc1.4d401f, 30fps, video only, 114.12MiB
18     mp4    640x360    360p  360k , avc1.42001E, 30fps, mp4a.40.2@ 96k (44100Hz), 87.29MiB (best)
```

As you can see the last option is listed as the best despite it's low resolution. There are a few ways we can get around this, I was trying to download from a channel that uploads in 720p so the easiest way was for me to use the `-f 'bestvideo[height>=720]+bestaudio/best'` flag.

Depending on your situation you might have to play with the format selector expression, perhaps either increasing it from 720 to 1080 or selecting a specific file format like mp4.

[To see other format selector examples](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#format-selection-examples)

[To see a full breakdown of the options](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#format-selection)

You will need to install ffmpeg or convert from mkv.

Comment: I would have made this a comment to the other thread, but you can't contribute without 50 reputation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this with `youtube-dl`.
But I recommend `yt-dlp`, it provides better download speed.

Example of Batch script for Windows.
Can be also adapted for Linux Bash.

Inspiration from Linux Bash script https://askubuntu.com/a/1022993/803975

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Downloads Video, converts into MKV and embeds subtitles
REM https://askubuntu.com/questions/1022855/download-everything-from-a-youtube-video-using-youtube-dl/1022993#1022993
IF NOT EXIST "./archive/videos/TZM_Archive/" MKDIR "./archive/videos/TZM_Archive/" 
IF NOT EXIST "./archive/videos/TZM_Archive/TZM_Archive.ytdlarchive" ECHO. > "./archive/videos/TZM_Archive/TZM_Archive.ytdlarchive" 
yt-dlp ^
--retries "3" ^
--no-overwrites ^
--call-home ^
--write-info-json ^
--write-description ^
--write-thumbnail ^
--all-subs ^
--convert-subs "srt" ^
--write-annotations ^
--add-metadata ^
--embed-subs ^
--download-archive "./archive/videos/TZM_Archive/TZM_Archive.ytdlarchive" ^
--format "bestvideo+bestaudio/best" ^
--merge-output-format "mkv" ^
--output "./archive/videos/TZM_Archive/%%(upload_date)s_%%(id)s/TZM_Archive_%%(upload_date)s_%%(id)s_%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" ^
"https://www.youtube.com/user/TZMOfficialChannel/videos"

IF NOT EXIST "./archive/videos/TZM_Archive/TZM_Archive.ytdlarchive" ECHO. > "./archive/videos/TZM_Archive/TZM_Archive_subtitles.ytdlarchive" 
REM Downloads additional externally available SUBTITLES to the folder of downloaded video
yt-dlp ^
--skip-download ^
--retries "3" ^
--call-home ^
--all-subs ^
--convert-subs "srt" ^
--output "./archive/videos/TZM_Archive/%%(upload_date)s_%%(id)s/TZM_Archive_%%(upload_date)s_%%(id)s_%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" ^
"https://www.youtube.com/user/TZMOfficialChannel/videos"


REM Downloads additional and missing THUMBNAILS
yt-dlp ^
--skip-download ^
--write-all-thumbnails ^
--ignore-config ^
--id ^
--output "./archive/videos/TZM_Archive/%%(upload_date)s_%%(id)s/TZM_Archive_%%(upload_date)s_%%(id)s_%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" ^
"https://www.youtube.com/user/TZMOfficialChannel/videos"
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 1):

The other two answers provide a good way to download all the videos from a youtube channel, but something that might come up is wanting to re-download the videos from a channel to get new videos they might have posted.

`youtube-dl` comes with an option which allows for this called `--download-archive`, it allows you to give a file which stores the videos you've already downloaded and then makes sure not to re-download them. It also writes to this file as it downloads new videos.

First we have to create this file for the videos we've already downloaded:

`create_download_list.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for n in *.*
do if [[ "$n" =~ -([-_0-9a-zA-Z]{11}).*$ ]]
   then echo "youtube ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" 
   fi
done > downloaded.txt
```

Now when you want to fetch new videos from the channel, you would just have to run:

```
youtube-dl --download-archive downloaded.txt ... <url-of-channel>
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late, I'd like to propose my [ytdownloader](https://github.com/kanehekili/YoutubeDownloader), which I offer as ppa for Ubuntu users:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jentiger-moratai/mediatools
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ytdownloader
```

As all of my apps, I try to keep the UI as simple as possible. The ytdownlaoder has been written to download the best quality video and audio (possibly using different servers)- it's backend is yt-dlp:

[image: 1]

The app works with drag'n drop on Gnome,XFCE and KDE