# How to bulk download videos and rename them simultaneously using youtube-dl?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, video, youtube, youtube-dl

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I want to download some [YouTube](http://youtube.com) videos. I came to know about the command line tool `youtube-dl` from this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63270/how-do-i-download-a-youtube-video). As mentioned by Yasser, using the command,

```
youtube-dl youtube.com/videolink --format mp4
```

I am able to download those video files in mp4 format.

Now I want to download ten videos from different channels. I have a text file with the YouTube links and the names by which I want to save them. The text file with name `data.txt` looks like,

```
http://youtube.com/link1    name1
http://youtube.com/link2    name2
http://youtube.com/link3    name3 
.........                   ......
.........                   ......
http://youtube.com/link10    name10
```

Now I want to run the `youtube-dl` command only once so that it takes the arguments from that text file automatically and save them with the required names.

If I have only the links in `data.txt`, i.e.,

```
http://youtube.com/link1
http://youtube.com/link2
http://youtube.com/link3 
.........
.........
http://youtube.com/link10
```

I am able to download the videos using the command only once with option `-a`,

```
youtube-dl --format mp4 -a data.txt
```

But I could not rename them simultaneously. From `man` page of `youtube-dl` I found that there is an option `--output` to set the filename.

How could I do that?

Comment: Can't you just place every url one after another? Like youtube-dl youtube.com/videolink youtube.com/videolink2 youtube.com/videolink3

Comment: It's manpage reads: `SYNOPSIS:
       youtube-dl [OPTIONS] URL [URL...]`, so yes, it should be possible to simple write one after the other.

Comment: Im writing a script to accomplish what you asked, do you want to be able to set the location where the file is gonna be stored?

Comment: Yes. It would be nice to set the location.

Comment: @Becerra, do you have any positive news?

Comment: My youtube-dl rename script is posted in this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/857989/get-watch-link-for-all-videos-of-a-youtube-channel/857992#857992 if you want to customize the rename part for your situation. The rename part of the script is this string: `'y/A-Z/a-z/'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only renaming files because you don't like the style by which `youtube-dl` names them, then you can use `--output` (or `-o`) with a template to customize the way it names all the files from Youtube metadata.

For example, `-o %(title)s.%(ext)s` will cause it to leave out the Youtube IDs from all of the filenames.

There are a lot of options, which may depend on your version of `youtube-dl`, so full details on this can be found at the terminal by typing:

```
man youtube-dl
/OUTPUT
```

---

However if you do want to name each file individually, you could instead run `youtube-dl` once for each line in the text file like this:

```
(while read URL NAME; do [ "$URL" ] && youtube-dl --format mp4 -o "$NAME" "$URL"; done) < data.txt
```

For each line, split it at the first run of one or more tabs and spaces into a URL and NAME, then if the line is not blank, pass them to `youtube-dl`. If the line just has a URL, the file will not be renamed.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is to use `config` file. On Linux and OS X, the system wide configuration file is located at `/etc/youtube-dl.conf` and the user wide configuration file at `~/.config/youtube-dl/config`. Note that by default configuration file may not exist so you may need to create it yourself.
I did not have any in my `~/.config`, so I had to create my configuration file. In there you can pass any argument you'd usually use with inline command in youtube-dl. Good use case is authentication with `.netrc` file and common use is the output format. Here is sample `config` file:

```
#Authentication with .netrc file
--netrc

# Save all videos in a directory named vimeo in your home directory
-o "~/Vimeo/%(title)s %(upload_date)s i%(id)s.%(ext)s"


# Download best format available via direct link over HTTP/HTTPS protocol
-f '(bestvideo+bestaudio/best)[protocol^=http]'

# Simple file name
--restrict-filenames
```

You can use `--ignore-config` if you want to disable the configuration file for a particular youtube-dl run. In essence, just like you're using `-a` switch to batch download, you can use `config` file to batch rename your downloads and tons of other customizations if you wish. 
Everything is documented with nice examples at [youtube-dl official documentations](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#readme), specially read the [CONFIGURATION](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#configuration)  & [OUTPUT TEMPLATE](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#output-template) sections.