# This file could harm your computer

Tags: files

After downloading the 4k software for downloading youtube videos, i get a message saying this file could harm my computer,keep or discard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete 4K Video Downloader and install youtube-dl (`sudo snap install youtube-dl`) instead. youtube-dl is a small command-line program to download videos from YouTube.com and other sites that don't provide direct links to the videos served.

youtube-dl allows the user, among other things, to choose a specific video quality to download (if available) or let the program automatically determine the best (or worst) quality video to grab. It supports downloading entire [playlists](https://askubuntu.com/q/334081) and [all videos from a given user](https://askubuntu.com/q/856911).

Example:

```
sudo snap install youtube-dl # installs the latest version   
cd ~/Desktop   
snap run youtube-dl -F https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6NZfCO5SIk
snap run youtube-dl -f 18 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6NZfCO5SIk
```

Note: youtube-dl is also able to recognize URLs of the form https://youtu.be/W6NZfCO5SIk

Comment: I have run the code on the terminal and everything is installed. How do i catch downloads now

Comment: Run `youtube-dl -F 'http://www.youtube.com/some-alphanumeric-string'` from the terminal to show the available formats without downloading a video.  Run `youtube-dl -f FORMAT 'http://www.youtube.com/some-alphanumeric-string'` to download the selected format where `FORMAT` is replaced by the selected format or `best` if you want the best available quality.

Comment: I get you now.The youtube url should be pasted in the terminal for it to capture the video I want to download right?

Comment: Right and one more thing. First change directories to your Desktop or Downloads directory or whatever directory that you want the video to be downloaded in (e.g. `cd ~/Desktop`) before you download the video.

Comment: Says this `youtube -dl -F 'https://youtu.be/W6NZfCO5SIk'
youtube: command not found`

Comment: after i ran this command `youtube -dl -F 'https://youtu.be/W6NZfCO5SIk'`

Comment: I added the correct command to my answer. Please install the youtube-dl snap package instead, because the apt package is currently not up-to-date.

Comment: The formats are showing well but i dont know how to download them

Comment: Send me the snap code please

Comment: I added the code to my answer.

Comment: Thanks alot. It worked