# How to open youtube video with youtube-dl

Tags: downloads, youtube-dl

Ok so I found this answer to someones question about how to download youtube videos via youtube-dl. It had all of the information that I needed, except how to open the video.

Here is what I have so far:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
youtube-dl youtube-video-link
```

It downloads ok, I just don't know how to open it. Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: Double click over file?

Comment: No it is not a link, it is a terminal program.

Comment: So you do `youtube-dl URL`, where `URL` is the URL of the video.

Comment: Yes I did this too, all it says is the video has already been downloaded. What I am wondering is how to open the downloaded video.

Comment: "I found this answer to someones question" Could you give the link? [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/145563/62483) is what you are looking for.

Comment: To open the downloaded video: double click over video!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63270/how-do-i-download-a-youtube-video is the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the directory where the video will be saved using the `-o` option.

Example:

```
youtube-dl -o "/home/<User>/Downloads/%(title)s" {URL}
```

The syntax to open any file in its default application is:

```
xdg-open $file
```

If you are using VLC player, you can use so:

```
cd /path/videos
vlc "Videoname.avi"
```

If VLC Player is not installed, you can install it so:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the answer. As Lucio stated, you double click on the file, I just didn't know where to find it to do this, and it is in the home folder.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best way to set the location of all of your downloaded files is to set this from within youtube-dl's configuration file which can be located as *$HOME/.config/youtube-dl.conf*. Syntax is:

```
--output "~/media/%(title)s.%(ext)s"
```

and of course change the path to suit your needs (and the extension template details if you wish). Otherwise youtube-dl will simply download the requested file in the working directory. This will only work with relatively recent versions of youtube-dl so it would be best to update your copy before trying this with the following command:

```
sudo youtube-dl --update
```

Now you will be able to easily find your downloaded files and play them back with VLC, SMPlayer or whatever your favoured media playback application is :)