# I can't figureout how to download youtube videos with the help of uget and flashgot addon

Tags: firefox, download-manager, uget

I am on ubuntu 14.04 and have installed uget from the official ppa and also installed flashgot addon for firefox. In addition I have also downloaded the aria2 plugin and enabled it in the plugin settings of uget. The problem is whenever I try to download any video from youtube, uget just downloads a small file named "watch" which is of around 180 KB and says download complete. I have tried searching for the solution but they were for older versions of uget and didn't work for me. Any insight will be helpful. Here are the link to the screenshots.

[image: ss1]

[image: ss2]

Comment: While your question is on topic here it's also independent of the operating system (Firefox add-ons usually are). You may reach a broader relevant audience on our sister site [SU].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I download a YouTube video?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63270/how-do-i-download-a-youtube-video) Alternatively this question is also off topic as non-reproducible because it's been abandoned by the author for years.

Answer (score 0):

uGet does not currently have support for YouTube downloading . . . it is on the roadmap but there is not an ETA for when it will happen. Sorry.

Comment: is there any news for youtube support?

Comment: it is possible to do so with the FlashGot addon but it is not yet possible with uGet directly.

Comment: I have Flashgot but I don't know how to use it honestly, it sometimes grab the downloadable links, sometimes it make Firefox downloading. Didn't work properly and I don't know what to do with it

Comment: FlashGot never takes over downloads you right click a link including YouTube links and use the FlashGot options in the context menu. "FlashGot Link" is what you will want to choose. You will also need to set uGet as the download manager in the general settings of FlashGot to work properly.