# How do I grab video from webofstories.com?

Tags: firefox, video, downloads

I am trying to download videos from "web of stories" (http://www.webofstories.com/). I tried all suggestions on [How can I access Flash files from streaming websites?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37267/how-can-i-access-flash-files-from-streaming-websites), but no one worked.
My browser is Firefox 11.0. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you just trying to watch them or download them?

Comment: I would like to download the videos to watch them later at home, where my connection is too slow for video streaming.

Answer (score 1):

Well I had written an answer for actually doing this with `flvstreamer` but as somebody who deals with video streaming professionally, I thought I'd check out the [terms and conditions](http://www.webofstories.com/contact) and doing what you're proposing is directly against the will of the project:

> [6. c.] you agree not to access any content made available on the Web Site including without limitation Material through any technology or means other than the playback facilities of the Web Site itself or such other means as WEB OF STORIES may explicitly designate for this purpose;

It's not just about copyright, hosting this stuff costs money. They're hosting it on S3/Amazon so it's actually costing them a *lot* of money. Every gigabyte streamed to you costs them between $0.12 and $0.25 on top of the S3 storage.

In short: if you want a load of their video, ask them.

Comment: As he is just using them for his personal use it should not be much of a problem legally

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether www.webofstories.com is compatible, but you can use www.keepvid.com to try and download it. That downloader is platform and browser independent and relies on a javascript to work. It may not work, but  why not give it a try!