# Please provide me the way to download "Youtube Video Downloader"

Tags: downloads, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to download flash (streaming) videos from sites like youtube, dailymotion, vimeo, etc.?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11211/how-to-download-flash-streaming-videos-from-sites-like-youtube-dailymotion-v)

Please tell me the way to download youtube video downloader.....

OS: Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

You can use Minitube YouTube downloader.  To install it

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/minitube
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install minitube
```

Or from USC

[image]

Comment: Without adding a third party repository I can recommend `youtube-dl`. Youtube-dl is a command line downloader for youtube playlists and videos. Optionally it can convert videos to mp3 (or other audio formats). It has now graphical user interface. Use `sudo apt-get install youtube-dl` to download it.