# help download and install and save and use my wireless stick modem and software

Tags: installation, wireless, networking, windows-7

I installed Linux (Ubuntu) after my Windows operating system went totally dead with a fatal blue screen. I could not  reboot or install form CD ROM or get safe mode.

Now that I've installed Ubuntu, I am still unable to install my wireless stick USB modem to connect and surf the Internet via provider. I'm using a wireless network from the neighborhood right now.

I find it difficult to download and install and save programs and applications from the Internet, including Skype and Real Player.

Ubuntu is different form Windows and not that easy to use. I click to download for example and find Real Player but when click on it it opens as a text file only and I cannot use it as it should be used for video and download and record from YouTube.

How can I do this? And does Ubuntu have a similar program to those available for Windows, to download/record YouTube videos?

Is there any trick to recover my Windows operating system? Can I use Linux to recovery the broken Windows system? Can I import my files from the broken Windows 7 system that always bluescreens?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to download and install from the internet >> skype and realplayer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/160912/how-to-download-and-install-from-the-internet-skype-and-realplayer)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. **In particular, you should post a separate question about using Ubuntu to recover your files from the broken Windows system. You most certainly *can* do this, but that's a different topic from how to install software on Ubuntu.** Thanks! Also, see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/11211/22949) (and Related questions) about getting durable files from YouTube.

Answer (score 2):

To install software in Ubuntu, we prefer to use Ubuntu Software Centre. To open Software Centre, open the dash (press the Windows key or click the Ubuntu logo on the left side of the screen) and search for it.

Skype is available from the Software Centre. Just search for it, or [click here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/skype/).

RealPlayer, on the other hand, is not particularly excellent for Ubuntu and it is not available in the Software Centre. Unless you were using some of its more exotic functions you should be fine without it. When you try to open a video or audio file, Ubuntu might offer to install some software to play it. You can get all of that right away if you install [Ubuntu restricted extras](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/ubuntu-restricted-extras/).

If you know you definitely need RealPlayer, [this web page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RealPlayerInstallationMethods) has some more information. In essence, RealPlayer is completely unsupported and unmaintained for Ubuntu, but you can download an [old version via the Helix Community](https://player.helixcommunity.org/2005/downloads/). You would need to download the 32-bit RPM version of RealPlayer 11, and use a tool called [Alien](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RPM/AlienHowto) to install that on Ubuntu. Not very pretty, so let's only worry about that if you're *sure* you need RealPlayer.

Sometimes you can get newer versions of software from other places, such as the Skype website. However, keep in mind that in doing so you will probably not receive automatic security updates. The Software Centre makes this kind of thing much easier. With that said, to download Skype from the Skype website you would need to follow the links to the [Skype for Linux](http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/get-skype/on-your-computer/linux/) page, then choose to download for Ubuntu 32-bit or Ubuntu 64-bit, depending on which version of Ubuntu you have installed. (If you aren't sure, you probably have 32-bit Ubuntu, but you can double check if you open System Settings / Details and look for the "OS type" label).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Eliah! I changed my answer a little. Feel free to edit it yourself if you catch anything else :)