# Download tv sohu

Tags: 12.04

Ho do i download these videos in ubuntu? In windows getflv software was used. I tried many flash video helper like downloadhelper without any luck

[link](http://my.tv.sohu.com/u/vw/32813316)

Comment: There are many utilities and techniques that can be used to download flash videos. See [How to download flash (streaming) videos from sites like youtube, dailymotion, vimeo, etc.?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11211/how-to-download-flash-streaming-videos-from-sites-like-youtube-dailymotion-v) If you try *all* of those ways and none work, please edit your question to provide detailed information (about everything you tried, with details of what happened for each). Until then, this question may be considered a duplicate of that one.