# Download Streaming Video

Tags: video, websites, video-streaming

I want to download any streaming video from websites.I already know that there are add-ons in firefox for youtube streaming video download.Please tell me how to download any streaming video from news and educational websites.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/11211/how-to-download-flash-streaming-videos-from-sites-like-youtube-dailymotion-v

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63270/how-do-i-download-a-youtube-video

Answer (score 8):

Try [VideoDownloadHelper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/). This firefox extension works on pretty much every website.

Anyhow, be aware that it might be **illegal** to download streaming content.

Comment: I know this add on,but it downloads only from youtube. I want to download videos from sites like ted.com and wallstreetjournal websites.

Comment: ted.com has a download link.

Comment: Saket, I have used Video Download helper on sites other than youtube.

Answer (score 1):

`youtube-dl` works on almost on all video sites. To use it open a terminal and type in `youtube-dl "link-to-video"`

Answer (score 0):

You can try [4k downloader](http://4kdownload.com). It downloads Youtube, Vimeo etc. It's free and open-source.

Comment: I know this add on,but it downloads only from youtube. I want to download videos from sites like ted.com and wallstreetjournal websites.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer online downloader, you can try [this one](http://downloadvube.com/) which I think is better than others among those downloaders I have used. With it, you can download streaming videos with no problem at all.

Comment: Linked Website has been closed.