# How can I update adobe flash player when Adobe doesnt support linux anymore?

Tags: flash

Im trying to update my Adobe to be able to be able to play games, watch youtube etc etc.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You may want to specify which version of Ubuntu you are running (11.10, 12.04, 12.10 etc.)

Answer (score 11):

You go and download [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com.mx/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDoQFjAA&url=http://www.google.com/chrome?hl=es&ei=mX3iUI-FNsrVrQGLkIH4Dw&usg=AFQjCNHUTrzEa7KrHE1Qn946QIa7DaSjXw&sig2=YZP4eHUg0Q5psv2WJQv6tA&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.b2U) to have the "latest" Flash available. Adobe will *not* release a new version of Flash (on any platform, add to that the lack of support for Linux), but it will continue to release security updates.

You can also try the free implementations of Flash. [Lightspark or Gnash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4329/stop-using-flash-or-improve-the-flash-experience). If you do not want to use Chrome and prefer Firefox for instance, you can install the package `flashplugin-installer`.

Comment: Excellent alternatives. This is why I love Linux.

Comment: Well, I said "Excellent alternatives", not: "Excellent FREE AND OPEN SOURCE Alternatives". I am sorry if this doesn't fit what you expect for an "alternative" but it is yet good for me. And it seems that we are -at least- 7 people who find this useful. Good luck and have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 1):

you could install the latest version of the adobe flash player through [pipelight](http://pipelight.net/cms/installation.html) which allows you to use its supported plugins nearly as if you use windows browser.

then you could keep the plugins up-to-date using `sudo pipelight-plugin  --update`